# SQL Server to update record in different database alternate solutions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I have DB-A1 which has a table T1 now i need that when ever T1.Status is changed then some columns will be updated on different DB-B1 in table T2.

I know how to achieve this via trigger but the problem is that i don't want to create triggers on DB-A1 due to some restrictions any other alternate way which should not affect the DB-A1 as DB-A1 is not mine.

Comment: The question is cleared i have a DB1 with table t1 now if any record update in the table i need to do somethings in my other database.But the problem is that on DB1 is client database not mine so i can't do much change on their DB level

Comment: They way SQL reports to data changes at the row&column level is triggers. Other mechanisms are meant for table- or row- level syncing and replication. Replication replicates everything, with some types of replication allowing you to filter the data. Change Tracking can give you all the PK values modified (or even deleted) since a specific database version, and even the columns that changed, but not the actual values

Comment: Check [About Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). The section [Using Column Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/work-with-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#using-column-tracking) shows how you can find which columns changed in each change operation